# Prevent ActiveRecord from rounding small numerical attributes ( < 1e-20)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, precision

I need my Rails app to work with some very small numbers i.e. less than `10e-20`. To do that I need to interact between three different systems, my database (Postgres), ActiveRecord and Ruby itself. Both Ruby and Postgres seem to be happy to deal with numbers that are as small as 1e-307. However I'm struggling to get ActiveRecord to play ball.

*[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html)*

> The double precision type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of at least 15 digits

*[Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Float.html)*

> MIN
> The smallest positive normalized number in a double-precision floating point. Usually defaults to 2.2250738585072014e-308.

So both Ruby and Postgres should be fine with numbers as small as `10e-307` and with around about 15 decimal places of precion.

#### Consider the following record

My 'Item' records have a rank attribute.

```rb
  # schema.rb
  create_table "items", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "rank"
    ...
  end
```

I can see from PSQL that the value of this for one particular record is `1.24324e-20`:

[image]

#### ActiveRecord is obscuring the precision

However, when I read this value via ActiveRecord it rounds it off to 1 significant figure:

```rb
myItem = Item.find('a60e5947-6e75-4c4e-8b54-c13887ad6bab')
myItem.rank
# => 0.1e-19
# (this should be 0.124324e-19)
```

And I can reconfirm that the precise value is in there using a raw SQL query:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select rank from items where id = 'a60e5947-6e75-4c4e-8b54-c13887ad6bab'").values
#=> [[1.24324e-20]]
```

#### This isn't a ruby issue...

I wanted to rule out the possibility that Ruby wasn't rounding the number so I took the value that was stored in Postgres and printed it straight into the console to check I could manipulate it:

```rb
1.24324e-20 + 1.1e-20
# => 2.34324e-20 (correct)
```

#### And it's not a Rails command-line formatting issue

Since values can sometimes be obscured by the formatting Rails uses to print to the command line, I wanted to check that too. To confirm it wasn't just a formatting issue I tried multiplying the number by 10e20 and adding another number to see if the precision was just hiding somewhere in Rails' formatting:

```rb
myItem.rank 
# => 0.1e-19
i.rank * 1e20 + 1.001
# =>  2.001
# (the answer should be 2.244239)
```

The precision from the original number (`1.34324`) is ignored in the calculation. So it's not a command-line formatting issue.

#### Why won't ActiveRecord respect the original precision?

What do I need to do to get ActiveRecord to keep up to pace with the precision of Postgres and Ruby?

### Please note: I don't want to switch the database column type

The 8-bit float column type is perfect for the numbers I wish to store. I don't need crazy precision, I just need very, very small numbers. I could switch the database column to `decimal` or `numeric` but it's a totally unnecessary amount of data to store.

Float is perfect for what I need - I just need ActiveRecord to actually read it correctly from the database....

Comment: What versions of everything are you using? I just tried this with Ruby 2.7.4 and Rails 6.1.4.1, seemed to preserve the precision of small numbers like `1.24324e-20`.

Comment: I'm on Ruby 2.6.6 and Rails 6.1.4.1...

Comment: Ahem - I figured out what the problem was... answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ahem. So it turns out that during a previous database migration of the `rank` attribute I had assigned it a `decimal` type with a fixed precision.

Although I had migrated the database to using `float` for this attribute, I hadn't reloaded my console and so it was printing out the value as truncated by the previous `decimal` precision specification.

I was surprised that not only did the console need restarting but also so did my dev server, I had assumed that updated itself though apparently it didn't.

Anyway. Mystery solved. Doh.

Comment: Highly recommend avoiding float with a precision of that magnitude instead use a decimal and set an appropriate precision. Floating point math is a very bad idea if precision is important

Comment: Unfortunately I really need the speed of a float. If I use a decimal (in Javascript) then the conversion to and from string really slows everything down. So my approach instead is to monitor the precision required to distinguish items and then re-rank them when it falls to below a critical level